# How to display calendar in my adapter of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, calendar, adapter

I have a `recyclerview`.  by clicking the button in each item of my list , my calendar is displayed for editing datetime...But calendar needs `ondatasetlistener` to be displayed.. I passed my activity to `adapter` but i dont know how to get `datasetlistener` from that.
    here my code in adapter :

```
  txtdateof.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PersianCalendar now = new PersianCalendar();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                       (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)activity ,
                        now.getPersianYear(),
                        now.getPersianMonth(),
                        now.getPersianDay()
                );
                dpd.setThemeDark(true);
                dpd.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        sdate.setText(year+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+dayOfMonth);
                    }
                });
                dpd.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "tpd");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you want to change dates in each row or want to get the selected date in Activity class?

Comment: Change dates in each row

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 private ArrayList<DataSet> dataSetArrayList;
     @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
            DataSet dataSet = dataSetArrayList.get(position);
            viewHolder.sdate.setText(dataSet.getTime());
            // you can format calendar text before setting it to textview.
            ... 
        }



            class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
                TextView  tv_time;


                MyViewHolder(View contentView) {
                    super(contentView);
                    tv_time = contentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
                    tv_time.setOnClickListener(this);
                    ....
                }


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (view.getId() == tv_time.getId()) {
                        showPicker(dataSetArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                    }
                }

            }

            public void setData(ArrayList<DataSet> list) {
                this.dataSetArrayList = list;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            private void showPicker(final DataSet dataSet) {
                Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        dataSet.setTime(newDate);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                fromDatePickerDialog.show();
            }
```